# textviews in one line, cutting off last textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a horizontal LinearLayout with 3 main textviews and 2 textviews to divide the 3 main textviews. The content of the textviews is dynamic. Some times its extremly short and some time its very long. They should all be centered in the middle and they should stay together with no space between them. My main problem is that if one textview is very long that it cuts of the other textviews...

Here is the Layout code:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/network"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Network 1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeholder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" - "
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Genre 1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeholder2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" - "
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/runtime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="120'"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In example: if the genre textviews is very long, the runtime textview doesnt show any content. I also tried to set the layout weight to 1 of the genre textview but then there is much space between the placeholders and the genre textview... So that wouldn't fix my problem.

Some screenshots do show what I mean:

Textviews without weight: [No weight](http://imgur.com/a/vRCyU)

Textviews with weight: [With weight](http://imgur.com/a/rylq0)

Any suggestions to fix it, that all cases look good?

Comment: Is it necessary to show all the genre's at once? If not you could use spinner to make the user select any one.

Comment: No, all genres should show at once, and that would only fix the problem that if the genre is too long, that the other views gets cut off, but if the network textview would be long, the other views also will get cut off